# How to record a screen with video AND audio on a Mac?

Tags: audio, video, screen-capture

I am using a Mac 10.14.6 and I want to record the full screen with both video and audio.

The reason is that I want to record a video from a German TV company, and neither `youtube-dl` work (there are DRM issues), nor a python script to download all `.ts` files during watching the livestream. So I figured the only possibility is to record the full screen for the duration of the video, like 3 hours.

To record the full screen I tried the `QuickTime Player` which was able to record the video, but no audio. Also, after recording only 5 minutes of the screen the size of the final 5-minute clip was about 2 GB (yes, 2 GB). That is WAAAAAAAY beyond anything reasonable.

So is there ANY other way, free tool, python tool, selenium-python possibility etc etc to record and/or download a 3 hour livestream from a webpage into a reasonable  sized file (1-2 GB Max) **with** audio?

Comment: By "DRM issues", you mean that the copyright owners of this stream don't want you to record the video?

Comment: Consider Handbrake to compress the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Recording the screen with sound using QuickTime Player can be done by the following methods.

- If you have audio input and output hardware (builtin or otherwise), then you can physically connect the output to input. I have done this using a 2011 iMac. The jacks are shown in the image below.

  [image: 2011 iMac]
- There is software that can redirect the sound heard from the speakers so this sound can be recorded by QuickTime while QuickTime is recording video from the screen. [SoundFlower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/tag/2.0b2) and [BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) both are free software which can do this. BlackHole is probably the better choice. If you choose to install SoundFlower you should read [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434624/installing-soundflower-on-intel-macs-with-big-sur-or-monterey).

Saving from QuickTime as a `.mov` file does take a lot of space. You can convert to a different format to save space. There are various `mov` to `mp4` converters are available on the web or from the App Store. For example, I used the [Free MP3 Converter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/free-mp4-converter/id693443591?&mt=12) by AnMP4 Studio to convert a 10.82 GB `mov` file made with QuickTime to a 1.26 GB `mp4` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I cannot record 3 hours and compress afterwards. That would be 72 GB, but I have only 40GB left

Comment: You could acquire a external drive with enough space to make the screen recording.